# Firebase how should I send localized push notification via REST API?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification

I did setup a PHP script that send push notifications via REST API

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

```
{
  "to": "DeviceID/Group",
  "notification": {
    "title": "My title",
    "body": "My message"
  }
}
```

Not sure how can localize the string

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem: what is keeping you from sending a localized title/body to the device?

Comment: I don't know if I can send the same message localized in one push. I saw the documentation but I can't find an example and is hard to test since I'm not the developer of the App